# Springboot server wont start, Enterprise application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, flyway

Hello Im a current student and total JEE noob, Im creating a multi-module project with mvn and when I start the server from my application.java I get this error and im not quite sure how to fix it..I got an exam coming up and Im pretty stressed out so any help is greatly appreciated! Sorry if this is a trivial problem and/or question.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

[INFO] Starting Application on DESKTOP-4KFU8LQ with PID 9036 (C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\mockExam\frontend\target\classes started by Kevin in C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\mockExam)
[INFO] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[INFO] Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[INFO] Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 19ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
[INFO] Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ce869900] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO] Bean 'org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.javaxfaces.JsfBeansAutoConfiguration$Jsf2_3AutoConfiguration' of type [org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.javaxfaces.JsfBeansAutoConfiguration$Jsf2_3AutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dea1e2b5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO] Bean 'org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.javaxfaces.JsfBeansAutoConfiguration' of type [org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.javaxfaces.JsfBeansAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92d067bb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO] Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[INFO] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[INFO] Starting service [Tomcat]
[INFO] Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
[INFO] At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[INFO] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[INFO] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1929 ms
[INFO] Resolving classes for com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer took 1.038s
[INFO] Initializing Mojarra 2.3.8 ( 20181116-0037 55af8b79ca53ec2df566f9c08a430259d30f9ba5) for context ''
[INFO] JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
[WARN] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
[INFO] Stopping service [Tomcat]
[INFO] 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[ERROR] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at org.example.mockexam.Application.main(Application.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.checkLocationExists(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:194)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.flyway(FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4e8466a0.CGLIB$flyway$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4e8466a0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$92d06f5a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4e8466a0.flyway(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 22 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Spring(boot) != JavaEE 9and JEE is a wrong abreviation

Comment: I see you are using flyway for database schema upgrade.
Did you create src/main/resources/db/migration/ directory?

Comment: Yes, https://gyazo.com/f64d8ff42de1b51a20a0ecf36dda7748

Comment: @Kukeltje JavaEE 9 is also a wrong abbreviation yet.

Comment: That should have bee an ( (shift did not work) and the close bracket, ),  was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration]

Either add the appropriate migrations, or if they're in the right place, check their namings.

Proper location for your migrations, i.e. the `classpath:db/migration`, is `src\main\resources\db\migrations` folder.

Proper naming logic can be found [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#naming-1).

Comment: Ok  thanks, this is my backend part, can you see anything wrong? https://gyazo.com/a713cd331e84eab2c53c90737b091393

Comment: is `db.migration` just one package? it should be `resources -> db -> migration`

Comment: You were correct it was only one package! I split it up and now Im getting this instead:   
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE, 

Here is my application.yml file: https://gyazo.com/7149648e598b69924d2904e9a3242428

Comment: You're having h2:mem database and you're telling to Spring that the driver it should use is Postgresql? By the way, it's always nice to upvote and accept the answer if it helps your problem.

Comment: Yeah I just cant see where I have stated that.. Im new to this forum so my upvote wont be publicly displayed yet lol

Comment: Are you having the correct dependencies? do you have driver for H2 database? or Postres? see your log, it says `Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB`. Postgres driver doesn't accept jdbcUrl of h2 database.

Comment: Im using h2 for tests and postgres else. The problem was a h2 dependency in the frontend-module that was not scoped to test. Thanks alot for all your help :)

Comment: Man, you're having a complicated configuration then, and I bet you should use Google. I answered already few questions and helped you solve few problems, but seems like you need to have several other changes. Stackoverflow is for asking/answering particular questions and not for teaching Spring boot configuration. Always pay attention to the logs: it tells you, that Postgres driver is used by JDBC attempting to connect to H2, which rightfully throws a run-time exception.

Comment: Yes I know, my initial problem got solved and that was basically what I was after. Ty again, and as my earlier comment mentioned, I solved that problem!

Comment: Try this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases or use just Google..

Answer (score 0):

the error log description "Cannot find migrations location in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migrations or check your Flyway configuration)" plz show more information about Flyway configuration

Comment: Is this not correct? https://gyazo.com/f64d8ff42de1b51a20a0ecf36dda7748

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have any flyway migrations just yet, if so you can remove flyway dependency from gradle or maven for now, it should help to start the application.
If you decide that you want to have migrations then add flyway back, and create folder called db/migrations in your classpath, and add a migration file there.

Comment: Dont have enough reputation to post the picture directly on the post, but here you go: https://gyazo.com/f64d8ff42de1b51a20a0ecf36dda7748

Comment: This looks just about right. Try adding these flyway settings to application.properties as well:  spring.flyway.check-location=true
# Whether to enable flyway.
spring.flyway.locked=false
spring.flyway.encoding=UTF-8
# The locations of migrations scripts.
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.out-of-order=false
# schemas to update
spring.flyway.schemas=your_schema
spring.flyway.sql-migration-suffixes=.sql
spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix=
spring.flyway.table=table_for_migration_tracking
spring.flyway.validate-on-migrate=false